# Failure to run the exe file

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have written a simple software for creating passwords. But when converted to exe and run file, the terminal screen closes after about 1 second.I have also installed all the modules. The software is available at the link below.Please help me.
https://gofile.io/d/0G6N1o

Comment: Try running it in the terminal and see if there are any errors

Comment: Post your code please, we don't want to download software from unreliable sources.

Comment: are you run this program on windows?

Comment: thank you for your help. that link its my codes(its not an software).
yes. i am running in the windows.
my IDE is visual studio code. when i am runing code in terminal of that, it dosent have problem But out of IDE VSC, it has problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is closing is because your application completed. You either need to have a dialog box which allows the user to click close, or at a minimum a sleep before you call exit(). This is the same for a .bat script in which the behavior you describe is a terminal window flickering for a second and going away.